# Django Connection Pooling to Postgresql

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, database-connection

After two days of searching, I thought someone here might be able to help me.

I am using Python 3.6 and Django 2.0.4 and pulling client data from a Postgresql database.
We process the data to create trends for each client.
We then check to see if a trend currently exists and either add a new one or update the existing entry.

When this app was single threaded it worked as expected, but was slow.
Now that I've tried to add simple multithreading, I'm quickly maxing out my database connections.

From what I've read, Django should be using the existing connection instead of opening new connections, but that's not what I'm seeing.

Below is a simplified version of what I'm doing.
What am I doing wrong and what can I do better to stop opening new db connections?

I've looked at pgPool and gpBouncer, but shouldn't Django handle this itself?

```
def trend_starter(date_to_trend, grouping):
    customer_list = Clearance.objects.distinct('customer').values_list('customer', flat=True)

    thread_list = []
    for cust_name in customer_list:
        trend_object = TrendSetter(customer=cust_name, mode='RT')
        trend_thread = threading.Thread(name=cust_name, target=trend_object.trend_setter)
        thread_list.append(trend_thread)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
        sleep(1)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()


class TrendSetter(object):
    def __init__(self, customer, mode):
        self.customer = customer
        self.mode = mode

    def trend_setter(self):
        customer_data = Clearance.objects.values_list('this', 'that').filter(customer=self.customer, mode=self.mode).order_by('-date')[:6]
        error_data = Clearance.objects.values_list('those').filter(customer=self.customer, mode=self.mode).order_by('-date')[:6] 

        #processing routine
        #var1 = some_array
        #var2 = some_array

        newtrend=False
        try:
            check_trend = Clearance.objects.get(customer=self.customer, mode=self.mode)
        except:
            newtrend = True

        if newtrend == False:
            check_trend.var1 = var1
            check_trend.var2 = var2
            check_trend.save()
        else:
            new_entry = Clearance(var1 = var1,
                                  var2 = var2)
            new_entry.save()
```